# how to detect which object is running a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I have a script which is going to go on all objects so when you hover over it shows its name but to do this different objects have different names so how would I detect in the code which game object is running the script as it runs certain parts when the mouse collides with the collider on the object so I need to know what is the name of that object. Thank you

Comment: inside the script, you just do something like "gameObject.name", that will give you the name of the object that has the scrit running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The object running the script is the one the script is attached to: `this.gameObject`

As the comment from Lestat said, "use something like `gameObject.name`", however I'll point out that this is the name assigned to the GameObject and spawened items (anything created using an `Instantiate` command) will have "(Clone)" appended to whatever the name of its prefab was. This may not be ideal.

However, if you have another script attached to every game object that has a public string field that stores the object's name, you can use `gameObject.GetComponent<ThatNameScript>().name` instead, where `ThatNameScript` is the name of whatever script you're using to store an object's name.